# Why does my encryption/decryption-pair give only sometimes the original plaintext back?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, urlencode, mcrypt

I am trying to encrypt a user id of format = LETTERS1234
it could contain a bunch of letters in the left and will end up with at least 1 number

I made a simple test website using this code:

```
<?php
    $key = 'rsZOkGnJiQKf6zkZ';
    $token = $_REQUEST['c'];
    if(!$token){
        $string = 'bgoogl1';
        $enc = urlencode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key),
                                        strtolower($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                                        md5(md5($key))));
        header('Location: http://website.com/test.php?c='.$enc);
    } else {
        echo rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key),
                                  urldecode($token), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                                  md5(md5($key))),"\0");
    }
?>
```

The result will give me most of the time the right output for any `$string`, but for this case and some other `$string` cases, it will fail and output something like this:

```
Ia$ÿ/ckY@Š«° =Û™¼îa¸ï³éÃ°1œ_¹0Àã ¼/÷d‡¬ÐöT¨i“\M~¯D”¯“ÚÍ
```

How could I fix this?

P.S. I've tried with rawurlencode and base64_encode and decode as well.

Comment: The reason this won't work is documented in [this W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2) -- `urlencode` is *not* binary safe -- see the [notes in the urlencode documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for the suggested workaround.

Comment: It would help to have a specific test string that fails. Without one, the test case is incomplete.

Comment: the given one fails 'bgoogl1'

Comment: Just a note (not related to the problem): It is not a good idea to use a constant initialization vector. Even more, your initialization vector consists of only hexadecimal digits, not fully (pseudo-)random data. Don't do this. (The same applies to the key.) (Also, do you really need the 256-bit block version of Rijndael? This is not AES.)

Comment: even if I do a AES encryption it fails, so I am assuming its all just about how the data is encrypted in the url. I tried to use utf8encoding and didn't work either

Comment: @luis: using the sample code, 'bgoogl1' works for me under Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3.4, OS X 10.6.8 and Chrome 15 or FF 8 using Base64 or URL (via `urlencode`, `rawurlencode` or `http_build_query`) encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you want to pass binary data in a HTTP request, you will [convert it to hexadecimal](http://php.net/bin2hex) instead:

```
$data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,md5($key),strtolower($string),MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,md5(md5($key)));
$hex = bin2hex($data);
```

Then, you can [pack](http://php.net/pack) it back to binary:

```
$bin = pack("H*", $hex);
```

*Note*: If you have issues with a specific case, it would help to know which one.

Comment: it returns: Type H: illegal hex digit l in website/test.php on line 9
îŠgÛµ$>ÑÑ²•eÜ~‡gš±%P®8Ámø§d

Comment: @luis: Of course, that's already binary. Convert it to hex first, then pack it back to binary.

Comment: no, look I tried using 'google1' as the $string, and it put that: îŠgÛµ$>ÑÑ²•eÜ~‡gš±%P®8Ámø§d in the browser (as a result of the hex operation). and then when it tried to pack it back it failed.

Comment: @luis: But obviously it is not hex encoded, so your attempt to hex encode it failed. Try experimenting with `pack()` and `unpack()` to see how to go from binary to hex and back again.